# How to select records with duplicate just one field and all other field value?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table name = `schedule`

```
 --------------------------------------------
| course_id | room |   day  |     time     |
--------------------------------------------
|     2     |  401 |saturday| 9:00 - 13:00 |
--------------------------------------------
|     3     |  401 | sunday | 9:00 - 13:00 |
--------------------------------------------
|     2     |  402 | monday | 9:00 - 13:00 |
--------------------------------------------
|     3     |  403 | tuesday| 14:00 - 17:00|
--------------------------------------------
|     4     |  401 | tuesday| 9:00 - 13:00 |
--------------------------------------------
|     2     |  402 |wednesday|14:00 - 17:00|
--------------------------------------------
```

and another table name = course

```
----------------------------------
| id | course_code | course_name |
----------------------------------
| 2  |  cse        | cse         | 
------------------------
| 3  |  eee        | eee         | 
----------------------
| 4  |  ct         | ct          | 
-----------------------
```

Now how to get output like this..

```
----------------------------------
| course code | course name | info |
----------------------------------
|cse          |  cse        |401,satueday-9:00-13:00; 402,monday-9:00-13:00; 402,wednesday-14:00-17:00|
------------------------
|    eee      | eee         | 401,sunday-9:00-13:00;403,tuesday-14:00-17:00 |
------------------------
|    ct       |  ct         | 401,tuesday-9:00-13:00|
-----------------------
```

Comment: I am not sure how to make table in stack overflow? For this reason my table structure is not good..

Comment: php Myadmin database.

Comment: Check [**HERE**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables) for table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group_concat

```
select c.course_code,
    c.course_name,
    group_concat(concat(s.room, ',', s.day, '-', s.time) separator ';')
from course c
join schedule s on s.course_id = c.id
group by c.course_code,
    c.course_name;
```

Comment: can i use WHERE condition in this query? like this    select c.course_code,
    c.course_name,
    group_concat(concat(s.room, ',', s.day, '-', s.time) separator ';')
from course c
join schedule s on s.course_id = c.id
group by c.course_code,
    c.course_name WHERE example=8;

Comment: @KuntalGupta Your table doesnt have example? But yes you can include that where

Comment: oh Sorry it just type mistake.

Comment: @juan Carlos Oropeza select c.course_code,
    c.course_name,
    group_concat(concat(s.room, ',', s.day, '-', s.time) separator ';')
from course c
join schedule s on s.course_id = c.id
group by c.course_code,
    c.course_name where s.department_id=8; i am trying this but it says syntax error!!!

Comment: @KuntalGupta try this.....select c.course_code, c.course_name, group_concat(concat(s.room, ',', s.day, '-', s.time) separator ';') from course c join schedule s on s.course_id = c.id where s.department_id=8 group by c.course_code, c.course_name