# my sql join Query with have count

Tags: sql

I am not sure how it can be done. If have any solution please help me....
i have 2 table `course` and `schedule` now i want to show all data from course and if schedule table have any data then show it..

i have table name = `schedule`

```
 --------------------------------------------------------
| course_id | room |   day  |     time     |
--------------------------------------------
|     2     |  401 |saturday| 9:00 - 13:00 |
--------------------------------------------
|     3     |  401 | sunday | 9:00 - 13:00 |
--------------------------------------------
|     2     |  402 | monday | 9:00 - 13:00 |
--------------------------------------------
|     3     |  403 | tuesday| 14:00 - 17:00|
--------------------------------------------
|     4     |  401 | tuesday| 9:00 - 13:00 |
--------------------------------------------
|     2     |  402 |wednesday|14:00 - 17:00|
--------------------------------------------
```

and another table name = course

```
----------------------------------
| id | course_code | course_name |
----------------------------------
| 2  |  cse1        | cse         | 
---------------------------------
| 3  |  eee        | eee         | 
---------------------------------
| 4  |  ct1        | ct          | 
---------------------------------
| 5  |  ct2        | ct          | 
----------------------------------
| 6  |  cse2        | ct          | 
----------------------------------
```

Now how to get output like this..

```
----------------------------------
| course code | course name | info |
|----------------------------------
|cse1|cse|401,satueday-9:00-13:00; 402,monday-9:00-13:00; 402,wednesday-14:00-17:00|
|------------------------
|cse2|cse|not assigned|
|----|---|-----------------
|eee |eee|401,sunday-9:00-13:00;403,tuesday-14:00-17:00 |
|----|---|-----------------
|ct1 |ct |401,tuesday-9:00-13:00|
|----|---|----------------
|ct2 |ct | not assigned|
|----|---|----------------
```

Comment: Your must've tried something . . . at least joining the tables together.

Comment: i am not sure how to do this....can you give some hint.

Comment: How is different to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812279/how-to-select-records-with-duplicate-just-one-field-and-all-other-field-value ?

Comment: And I show you the link to format the tables properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group_concat` function is your friend here (combined with `coalesce`).

```
select c.course_code, 
c.course_name, 
coalesce(group_concat(s.room, ', ', s.day, '-', s.time separator ';'), 'not assigned') info
from course c
left outer join schedule s on c.id = s.course_id
group by c.course_code;
```

Comment: probably missing `c.course_name` in your `GROUP BY`

Comment: It isn't needed.

Comment: its working fine...thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to join the two tables together, then aggregate your "schedules" to a single string value grouped on the courses.

Disclaimer : code is not tested as I don't have a MySQL db anywhere near!

I am used to Oracle so I did not know which function worked in MySQL to aggregate strings so after a quick search, I found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

```
SELECT c.course_code,
       c.course_name,
       CONCAT_WS(',',CONCAT(s.room,',',s.day,'-',s.time)) as info
FROM COURSE c 
LEFT JOIN SCHEDULE s ON c.id = s.course_id
GROUP BY c.course_code,c.course_name
```

It should yield a result close to what you are expecting, except for the "not assigned" which will do something I can't predict depending on how `WS_CONCAT` handles nulls.

**Explanation:**

`CONCAT_WS` is an aggregator function, much like `MAX` or `SUM`. Only, it takes a separator as firts argument, and the columns you want to aggregate after.

If you want to display extra columns (such as course code and name) when querying aggregates, you need to specify them in your `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, try changing `LEFT JOIN` for `INNER JOIN` and notice the difference : courses without schedules won't be returned.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is with the XML method:

```
SELECT room +  ' '  +  day + ' ' + time + ', ' AS 'data()' 
FROM schedule
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: This isn't valid mysql syntax.